# Looking for a windows binary of eAccelerator or APC for PHP 5.3.0. Anyone know where I can download?

Tags: dll, php

I've googled for hours, but I cannot seem to find the right `*.dll` file for either of these PHP caching solutions.  I'm running windows server 2003, Apache 2.2.11, and PHP 5.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found something on [this forum](http://www.waldbauer.com/vb/showthread.php?t=2148), but you'll need to register first or use something like [BugMeNot](http://www.bugmenot.com/view/waldbauer.com) to avoid useless registrations.

I download the zip file named `eAccelerator_PHP_5-3.zip` and it contains only one file called `eAccelerator.dll`. I hope this is what you want.

Otherwise, you could try something else like [WinCache](http://www.php.net/wincache).

Comment: Thanks for the research, and thanks for turning me on to wincache!